# Neo4j/Cypher - Filtering and returning on the same relation type

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

Lets say that I have some user nodes that `FOLLOWS` other nodes. I want to load a list of all users, along with *full* list of who they're following *and* filter that list to only get users that follow some specific nodes. What is the proper way to do that?

---

My first attempt was:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[:FOLLOWS]->following
WHERE following.name='John'
RETURN n, COLLECT(following)
```

Which obviously doesn't work as all the followed users are filtered except for John, so the COLLECT() always only has that single user.

---

My next attempt was to load the related nodes twice:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[:FOLLOWS]->following_filter
    , n-[:FOLLOWS]->following_all
WHERE following_filter.name='John'
RETURN n, COLLECT(following_all)
```

Which seemed to work well at first, but the moment I add another MATCH clause to that I start getting partial list of followed users again. Any idea why this is happening?

---

Another possible solution that does seems to work well is with `WITH` and `ANY`:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[:FOLLOWS]->following
WITH n, COLLECT(following) AS following
WHERE ANY(x in following WHERE x.name='John')
RETURN n, COLLECT(following)
```

However, I prefer avoid using `WITH` for now and find another solution. I'm generating those queries with a [query builder](https://github.com/shesek/cypher-query) I wrote that doesn't yet support `WITH`, and requires some architectural changes to add support for that, which'll take some time. I do realize that its not a very good reason to avoid `WITH`, and I will eventually add support for that - but I really prefer to get something working now and change it later if necessary.

---

I can also use the pattern as a WHERE clause:

```
START n=node(*), john=node(888)
MATCH n-[:FOLLOWS]->following
WHERE n-[:FOLLOWS]->john
RETURN n, COLLECT(following)
```

But it seems like I can only load my "John" node using an ID or lucene index, and loss the full expressive power of Cypher's WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH following_all<-[:FOLLOWS]-n-[:FOLLOWS]->following_filter
WHERE following_filter.name='John'
RETURN n, COLLECT(following_all)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with this as my second attempt - it works well until I add another MATCH clause. See here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/ys5z4l (note that Neo has two outgoing KNOWS relation, and that it returns both of them when the LOVES match is removed)

Comment: SO, you tried using `WITH` ?? but why do you avoid using it ?

Comment: I mentioned it in the question - I'm working with a query builder that doesn't support WITH. are there any alternative methods?

Comment: Have you tried using `Rest API` and run `Cypher` queries using it?? it works well for me, and it supports `WITH`..